# Помогите, ошибка TypeError: Quit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ev'

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from pygame import *


def Quit(ev):
    global root
    core122 = messagebox.askyesno("Сохранение файла", "Сохранить недоделанный файл?")
    if core122 == True:
        SaveFile(ev)
    elif core122 == False:
        root.destroy()
    elif core122 == None:
        root.destroy()
    print(core122)



def LoadFile(ev):
    fn = filedialog.Open(root, filetypes=[('*.all files', '.*')]).show()
    if fn == '':
        return
    textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox.insert('1.0', open(fn, 'rt').read())


def SaveFile(ev):
    fn = filedialog.SaveAs(root, filetypes=[('*.all files', '.*')]).show()
    if fn == '':
        return
    messagebox.showinfo('File Extension Error (021)', 'You must specify a file extension at the end!')
    open(fn, 'wt').write(textbox.get('1.0', 'end'))

def clsi():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("FRID Redactor")
    root.geometry('500x25')
    lbl = Label(root, text="Fander Company. 2022 - TestProduct", font=("Helvetica", 14))
    lbl.pack(fill = 'both')
def clsi1():
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('https://www.fadcomp.tk', new=0)

root = Tk()
root.title("FRID Redactor")
menu = Menu(root)
new_item1 = Menu(menu)
new_item2 = Menu(menu)
new_item3 = Menu(menu)
new_item1.add_command(label='About', command=clsi)
new_item1.add_command(label='Site', command=clsi1)
new_item2.add_command(label='Load', command=LoadFile)
new_item2.add_command(label='Save', command=SaveFile)
new_item2.add_command(label='Quit', command=Quit)
menu.add_cascade(label='Info', menu=new_item1)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item2)
root.config(menu=menu)

textFrame = Frame(root, height=340, width=600)

textFrame.pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=1)

textbox = Text(textFrame, font='Helvetica 18', wrap='word')
scrollbar = Scrollbar(textFrame)

scrollbar['command'] = textbox.yview
textbox['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

textbox.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

Выдает ошибку TypeError: Quit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ev'

Comment: у вас везде используется ev - откуда вы ее хотите брать?

Comment: @splash58 это так называемый event, это не переменная.

Comment: а вы уверены , что command передает какой-то event?

Comment: @splash58 не сильно уверен, но скажу одно, что ранее подобной ошибки не возникало

Comment: @splash58 по всей видимости в этом виновата вызов функции '''SaveFile(ev)'''

Comment: вы посмотрите описание add_command. я не уверен, что там какие-то аргументы передаются, мне кажется, что я lamdba использовал для этого. но это давно было. могу в исходники залезть

Comment: не могу сказать, как раз таким там и не нужно передавать аргументы в моем случае

Comment: да, я посмотрел - ничего не передается

Comment: @splash58 у меня другая ситуация

Comment: А попробовать передать без аргументов не получается

Comment: тогда и уберите во всех функциях аргументы

Comment: ну попробуем :\

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, @splash58. Можете добавить ответ и я его поставлю на лучший.

Comment: да, тут не про что ответ писать :)

Comment: @splash58 мне то и 16 нету, я лишь изучаю, мне ваша поддержка дороже любого алмаза :)

Comment: удачи! молодца!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то необходимо просто убрать аргументы в функциях LoadFile, SaveFile, Quit. Чтобы в них не было "ev".
Так должно быть:

```
def Quit():
    global root
    core122 = messagebox.askyesno("Сохранение файла", "Сохранить недоделанный файл?")
    if core122 == True:
        SaveFile()
    elif core122 == False:
        root.destroy()
    elif core122 == None:
        root.destroy()
    print(core122)



def LoadFile():
    fn = filedialog.Open(root, filetypes=[('*.all files', '.*')]).show()
    if fn == '':
        return
    textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox.insert('1.0', open(fn, 'rt').read())


def SaveFile():
    fn = filedialog.SaveAs(root, filetypes=[('*.all files', '.*')]).show()
    if fn == '':
        return
    messagebox.showinfo('File Extension Error (021)', 'You must specify a file extension at the end!')
    open(fn, 'wt').write(textbox.get('1.0', 'end'))
```